# App crashing after disabling arc

Tags: iphone, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have an already developed project for ios3 and ios4 developed on sdk4.but my app get crashed on ios 5 while it was working fine on lower version.

As my guess it's due to ARC concept of ios5.

So what i tried is

installed sdk 4.2.

refractor project from EDIT option for ARC.(I get some error while converting for arc.i continued).
Disabled arc from build settings.
also set the flag -fno-objc-arc

But no luck app still crashing.

it crash on accessing property value.

Comment: where's it crashing?  on what code?  any more info?

Comment: So "My app crashed when I tried to run it on iOS5 SDK. So I enabled ARC and it crashed. Then I disabled ARC againg and it still crashed. It must be ARC's fault!"

Comment: @NJones what u mean by writing this line

Comment: I meant that your reasons for blaming ARC seem dubious.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you guess it was ARC? ARC doesn't even happen unless you specifically ask it to do so. I'm betting it had more to do with an API change between ios 4 and ios5.

My advice is to use your source control to go back to your version before you made those changes, run it again on ios5, read the stack trace, and find out what is really causing your app to crash.

Comment: I have checked with older version with ios 5 device . it's getting crash. and reason is meesage sent to deallocated instance.while if i tried with ios 4 no such error. so that's why i was guessing

Comment: You shouldn't guess when you debug. APIs change between major releases and this sometimes causes latent issues in your code to bubble up to the surface when the previously did not. Again, I suggest you rollback your source code and find out what is causing the deallocated instance.

Comment: it's causing on accessing property value but not causing in case of ios4

Comment: Forget about the fact that it doesn't crash in iOS4, it is irrelevant right now. Show us the stack trace when it crashed. Tell how you create the property. Give us more information and maybe we can tell you why it is crashing.